# how to compile a grid search for a neural network in R

Tags: r, neural-network, h2o, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am trying to find the best parameters for my Neural Network I want to create in R. I am using the h2o package and following the tutorial from https://www.kaggle.com/wti200/deep-neural-network-parameter-search-r/comments

The code I have seems to run in 1 minute and from what I understood grid search should run multiple models until the best parameters are determined and that would take while to run. Please let me know where I am going wrong and how I can do the gird search to optimise my parameters.

```
h2o.init(nthreads=-1,max_mem_size='6G')
testHex = as.h2o(test)
trainHex = as.h2o(training)

predictors <-colnames(training)[!(colnames(training) %in% c("responseVar"))]
response = "responseVar"

hyper_params <- list(
  activation=c("Rectifier","Tanh","Maxout","RectifierWithDropout","TanhWithDropout","MaxoutWithDropout"),
  hidden=list(c(20,20),c(50,50),c(75,75),c(100,100),c(30,30,30),c(25,25,25,25)),
  input_dropout_ratio=c(0,0.03,0.05),
  #rate=c(0.01,0.02,0.05),
  l1=seq(0,1e-4,1e-6),
  l2=seq(0,1e-4,1e-6)
)
h2o.rm("dl_grid_random")

search_criteria = list(strategy = "RandomDiscrete", max_runtime_secs = 360, max_models = 100, seed=1234567, stopping_rounds=5, stopping_tolerance=1e-2)
dl_random_grid <- h2o.grid(
  algorithm="deeplearning",
  grid_id = "dl_grid_random",
  training_frame=trainHex,
  x=predictors, 
  y=response,
  epochs=1,
  stopping_metric="RMSE",
  stopping_tolerance=1e-2,        ## stop when logloss does not improve by >=1% for 2 scoring events
  stopping_rounds=2,
  score_validation_samples=10000, ## downsample validation set for faster scoring
  score_duty_cycle=0.025,         ## don't score more than 2.5% of the wall time
  max_w2=10,                      ## can help improve stability for Rectifier
  hyper_params = hyper_params,
  search_criteria = search_criteria
)                            

grid <- h2o.getGrid("dl_grid_random",sort_by="mae",decreasing=FALSE)
grid

grid@summary_table[1,]
best_model <- h2o.getModel(grid@model_ids[[1]]) ## model with lowest logloss
best_model
```

Comment: Suggestion: make the example above reproducible by adding a public dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `max_runtime_secs = 360` via `search_criteria` in the grid settings, so the longest it will potentially run is 6 minutes.

If the grid is stopping prior to that, it means that your early stopping settings are triggering the grid to stop early.  If you'd like it to run longer, then you can increase `stopping_rounds` for the grid and/or increase the `stopping_tolerance` and it should be less sensitive to stopping early and run longer (in the code above you have them set to `5` and `1e-2`, respectively).  You might also want to set `stopping_metric = "RMSE"`, since the default value for regression is mean residual deviance (`"deviance"`).  See more information about  stopping metric in the [user guide](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/stopping_metric.html).

I noticed that you have `stopping_rounds = 2` for the individual DNN models (you might want to try increasing that if your models are underfitting).

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you let me know what you think I should change stopping_tolerance and stopping_rounds to. I also have stopping_metric set to RMSE already, did you mean to change it to something else?

Comment: You can try changing them first to the default values, and after that you could follow my recommendations above to increase stopping tolerance.